# Guitar tuning BG#EF#BE

Tags: guitar, tuning

Just bought the tab (Peter Ciluzzi - Soliloquy) and it is said inside that the tuning is BG#EF#BE. I've been fighting with my simple nylon 6-string guitar trying to set this tuning but the song doesn't sound! 
My best attempt is (starting from standard EADGBE): -5/2 tone, -1/2 tone, -5 tone, -1/2 tone, unchanged, unchanged. But it doesn't sound. I would be grateful for any hint or, even more, for an instruction how to set this tuning up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a chromatic tuner, just match every string with the tuning indication, without thinking about semitones.

In any case, it would be `-5, -1, +2, -1, 0 0`.

In order to prevent the low string from buzzing, consider changing to an heavier gauge one if you plan to play in this tuning often.

Btw [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrLodeZCmCY) it mentions `B B D F# B D`, but of course you should trust the original tab better.

Comment: Seems like "-5, -1, +2, -1, 0 0" works! Thanks alot @moonwave99 !!!!